# how to implement android login with callback

Tags: android, authentication, callback

now I'm making a login for my website in android, but I am confused to implement a callback method to "receive response data from the server" is there anything that can help me deal with this problem?

thanks for the help...

Comment: post your code whatever you done

Comment: will you please post your code and elaborate what you want.